# Can't add a line number to the beginning of each line with awk

Tags: awk

I'm trying this awk command `awk "{print NR, $0}" file1.csv`, but it's adding the line number followed by a space and not a comma.

I tried other commands with the same results

```
awk "{print NR "," $0}" file1.csv
```

And I have an error wherever I use a single quote.

I'm using Gawk on Windows. I'm I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: The problem that the answers address without actually explaining, is that you have used double quotes which expand shell variable(which start with `$`, also if you look where the double qoutes are then you will notice the comma is not quoted, meaning it is seen by `awk` as a comma which is in turn represents the `OFS`(space).

Comment: Just use single quotes: `awk '{print NR "," $0}' file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers, but I found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5339734/471461) that work: on window I have to escape inside double quotes:

```
awk "{print NR \",\" $0}" file1.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Just include the awk's code inside single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
awk '{print NR "," $0}' file1.csv
```

OR

```
awk -v FS="," -v OFS="," "{print NR,$0}" file.csv
```

And your your previous command `awk "{print NR, $0}" file1.csv` displays space instead of comma because by default `,` in the print section  will print the value of Output Field Separator variable . The default value of `OFS` is space by default. So it displays space instead of comma.

Comment: I've tried it, but windows throws an error wherever I use a single quote

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '{print NR "," $0}' file1.csv
```

Example:

```
sdlcb@BlrLaite2-Generic:~$ cat ff
aa, aa, aa, aa
aa, aa, aa, aa
aa, aa, aa, aa
aa, aa, aa, aa
aa, aa, aa, aa
aa, aa, aa, aa
sdlcb@BlrLaite2-Generic:~$ awk '{print NR "," $0}' ff
1,aa, aa, aa, aa
2,aa, aa, aa, aa
3,aa, aa, aa, aa
4,aa, aa, aa, aa
5,aa, aa, aa, aa
6,aa, aa, aa, aa
```

Comment: I've tried it, but windows throws an error wherever I use a single quote

Answer (score 0):

Using a comma like in `"{print NR, $0}"` you are [printing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Print.html#Print) each term following print with the [field separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Default-Field-Splitting.html#Default-Field-Splitting).

Using double quotes in `awk "{print NR "," $0}"` you are *splitting* the command with a comma.

You have to use single quotes for the whole awk command:

```
awk '{print NR","$0}' file1.csv
```

Or use the [printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html#Basic-Printf) statement

```
awk '{printf("%s,$0\n", NR,$0)}' f
```

Answer (score 0):

The `,` in your `awk` is the default Field Separator, one space.
To get what you want chnage the Output Field Separator.

```
awk -vOFS="," '{print NR, $0}' file1.csv
```